# IF statement in query requires same value to be in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an `IF` statement in a query which joins several tables.

```
SELECT * FROM specimen, topography_index, morphology, functions 
WHERE 
SUBSTRING(specimen.topography_index, 2, 2) = topography_index.topography_index_code 
AND 
IF(specimen.snop_axis = 'M', morphology.morphology_code = specimen.snop_code, functions.functions_code = specimen.snop_code) 
AND specimen_pk = '$specimen'
```

The problem is if `specimen.snop_axis = 'F'`, and the value returned from `functions.functions_code` is not in `morphology.morphology_code`, then nothing is returned.

How should the query be written so that there is no join between `functons` and `morphology` tables so that the same values don't have to be in those tables?

Comment: Can you provide sample data with desired results?  A Fiddle would be nice... A little unclear how your query relates to your comments.

Comment: Not easily...but I'll have a go.  The problem is the joining of morphology and functions tables at the beginning of the query.  So if the same values don't exist in both tables and if snop_axis != 'M', nothing will be returned...despite there being a record in table specimen WHERE snop_axis = 'F' and the topography index condition being met

Comment: if there is an `F` your functions.functions_code should match  specimen.snop_code. Not morphology as you expect

Comment: Sure, but I have found that if snop_axis = 'F' then it will only return the specimen if there are corresponding values in both morphology and functions tables